# Setting up an Excel Doc to Save and Close after a period of inactivity

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to come up with a way to close an excel document after a period of inactivity. The problem i'm running into is that if excel is in Edit mode, the macro will not execute.  This would be for a workbook that is on a server that multiple people have access to, the problem is that some people leave it open and forget that they have it open and no one else can edit it hence the need for this.

I've create a VBA macro code that only closes the excel document while the user is not in edit mode:

```
Sub OpenUp()
Dim Start, Finish, TotalTime, TotalTimeInMinutes, TimeInMinutes
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
TimeInMinutes = 1 ' sets timer for 1 minutes
If TimeInMinutes > 1 Then
TotalTimeInMinutes = (TimeInMinutes * 60) - (1 * 60)
' times 60 seconds to "minutize"/convert time from seconds to minutes   
   Start = Timer    ' Sets the start time.
   Do While Timer < Start + TotalTimeInMinutes
       DoEvents    ' Yield to other Excel processes.
   Loop
   Finish = Timer    ' Set end time.
   TotalTime = Finish - Start    ' Calculate total time.
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    MsgBox "You've had this file open for " & TotalTime / 60 & "     minutes.  You have 1 minute to save all your files before Excel closes"
End If

Start = Timer    ' Sets the start time.
   Do While Timer < Start + (1 * 60)
       DoEvents    ' Yield to other Excel processes.
   Loop
   Finish = Timer    ' Set end time.
   TotalTime = Finish - Start    ' Calculate total time.
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ThisWorkbook.Save
   Application.Quit
End Sub
```

I know this request kind of defies logic as you don't want the workbook to close while someone is in the middle of a edit hence why you can't run a macro while in edit mode.  But if there is any way to set up some code to save and close a workbook after a certain set time period has passed i would have need of it in this circumstance.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need place the below code and save the file to XLSM type. Reopen the file to run the macro

Place the code in the standard module

```
Option Explicit

Public EndTime
Sub RunTime()
    Application.OnTime _
            EarliestTime:=EndTime, _
            Procedure:="CloseWB", _
            Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub CloseWB()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Place the code in the Thisworkbook Module

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:20") '~~> 20 Seconds
    RunTime
End Sub
```

Place this in each worksheet to detect any changes in the worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If EndTime Then 
        Application.OnTime _ 
        EarliestTime:=EndTime, _ 
        Procedure:="CloseWB", _ 
        Schedule:=False 
        EndTime = Empty 
    End If 
    EndTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:20") '~~> 20 Seconds
    RunTime 
End Sub
```

I have got the answer from this site 
http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/600241-excel-vba-close-workbook-after-inactivity.html